# HTML5 form layot issue with input field moving around

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML5 form which does some calculations using jQuery.

I found an issue that I had never seen before - if someone can figure out why and from where it is coming - when I enter data in the input fields, they move up, and the span element - which is the result moves down:

bit.ly/1xXEEa0

Comment: create a short sample which reproduces the error and use jsfiddle

Comment: Start by fixing your numerous HTML errors: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://chcdigital.com/Development/BudgetPlanner/ – there is no closing `</input>` tag in HTML5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying `float:left` for the inputs will fix the issue.

```
input {
  width: 33%;
  min-height: 30px;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: Nidheesh, thank you so much - it fixed the formatting, but after I input something, it still moves around?